# React native infinite scrollview with next previous buttons

Tags: javascript, react-native

I want to create a Infinite ScrollView like [react-native-infinte-scrollview](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-infinite-scrollview) in which views are created and deleted on scroll but this plugin doesn't provide next/previous buttons. I just want to add next and previous buttons because I have 10 gif files in my project and each gif is 7 to 10 MB in size and if I load all these gif files at the same time in scrollview, my app crashed.

Answer (score 0):

i dont know about this but i have logic here

```
constructor(){
  this.state = {
    pageNUmber:0,
    data:['url1','url2',url3]
  }
}

renderGif(){
  var data = this.state.data;
  return(
    <Image source={{uri:data[this.state.pageNUmber]}} ?>
  )
}

changePage(val){
  if(val=='next'){
    this.setState({
      pageNumber:this.state.pageNumber+1
    })
  }else{
    if(this.state.pageNumber!=0)
      this.setState({
        pageNumber:this.state.pageNumber-1
      })
  }

}


render(){
  return(
  <View>
    <ScrollView>
      {this.renderGif()}
    </ScrollView>
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>{this.changePage('next')}}>
      <Text>next</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>{this.changePage('previous')}}>
      <Text>previous</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  </View>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Im pretty sure that the difference between React Native's `ScrollView` and `FlatList` is that flatlist deletes content off the page. 
According to the [Docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist.html), you'll want to use Flatlist with horizontal enabled